# How can I get the sum of Counter objects from a rolling group by in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I'm trying to sum [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects in a group by rolling window in Pandas but I'm running into errors.

I need to get the sum of the **rolling next** 6 (or any other number) of days (from the date in the given row) of Counter objects in a new column. This needs to be grouped by the id.

*"**next 6**" clarification: This is NOT including current day. So for Jan 1, 2021, the next six days will be Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 4, Jan 5, Jan 6, Jan 7*

**Code to construct minimal example:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

ids = [111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222]
cntr = [Counter({'a': 1, 'b':2}), Counter({'c': 3}), Counter({'a':1, 'b':1}), Counter({'a': 1, 'b':2}), Counter({'c': 3}), Counter({'a':1, 'b':1}), Counter({'d':2}), Counter({'e': 3})]
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/04/2018').append(pd.date_range(start='1/08/2018', end='1/11/2018'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids, 'dates': dates, 'state_cntr': cntr})
```

The sample dataframe looks like:

```
    id  dates       state_cntr
0   111 2018-01-01  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1   111 2018-01-02  {'c': 3}
2   111 2018-01-03  {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
3   111 2018-01-04  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
4   111 2018-01-08  {'c': 3}
5   111 2018-01-09  {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
6   222 2018-01-10  {'d': 2}
7   222 2018-01-11  {'e': 3}
```

**Output Required**

```
    id  dates       state_cntr          output_needed
0   111 2018-01-01  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}    {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}
1   111 2018-01-02  {'c': 3}            {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}
2   111 2018-01-03  {'a': 1, 'b': 1}    {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}
3   111 2018-01-04  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}    {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3}
4   111 2018-01-08  {'c': 3}            {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
5   111 2018-01-09  {'a': 1, 'b': 1}    {}
6   222 2018-01-10  {'d': 2}            {'e': 3}
7   222 2018-01-11  {'e': 3}            {}
```

For me, `df.groupby(['id', 'dates'])['state_cntr'].sum()` at least sums the Counter objects, although that isn't exactly what I want. But the following gives me an error, because it seems to be trying to ensure that the value is a `float` (but what I have is a Counter), so, it throws a `TypeError`:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['id', 'dates'])
grouped_df['state_cntr'].sum().reset_index(level='id').groupby(['id'])['state_cntr'].rolling('6D').sum()
```

**Error**: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Counter'` and `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` (some other cascading ones)

I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: "But the following gives me an error" Think about the steps you're asking to take, and the order you're asking them to occur: first group by id and dates, then sum each group, then re-group the sums, then build rolling windows. It sounds like what you want is: first group by id (*not* by dates), then within each group build rolling windows, then sum the rolling windows.

Comment: Thank you Karl. I was a little hasty with my example. I've also tried `df.set_index('dates').groupby(['id'])['state_cntr'].rolling('6D').sum()` with the same error. Maybe I'm tired and not looking at this the right way. I'll come back to this and try to re-read your comment and figure it out tomorrow.

Comment: Out of interest, what motivates this Counter approach, as opposed to having `a`, `b` and `c` columns in your dataframe (which makes solving this problem trivial).

Comment: Multiple reasons. Primarily, because `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` are not the only keys. There are several keys and that could run into a large number (some key names may be unknown and come up later). Sure, I could split the dictionary into columns and do the rolling sum and then re-combine. But that still doesn't explain why the Counter approach, (which is a more elegant solution imo), does not work when you use the rolling window. Yet, it works for the regular groupby sum.